# Android, EditText not update the variable after pressing Done

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an EditText that let me type in the an IP address:
In the xml:

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/enterIP"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="enterIP"
            android:inputType="textPhonetic"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            />
```

I used android:imeOptions="actionDone" so that the input box will disappear after I press Done.
In the Java:

```
public void enterIP(View view) {
        EditText theIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterIP);
        try {
            myIP = theIP.getText().toString(); 
            validIP = ipvalidator.validate(myIP);
        } catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log.d("Error", "Input address is NULL.");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New IP is " + myIP, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

However, the problem with this is that when I pressed Done, myIP still holds the old value. Only when I touch the EditText to bring up the input again the value is updated.

So how can I make sure myIP will be updated when Done is pressed. ?

Thanks

Comment: `onClick()` will be called when you click the `EditText`. What you're experiencing is the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try this**

```
 yourEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    //do something
                    myIP = theIP.getText().toString(); 
            validIP = ipvalidator.validate(myIP);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
theIP.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // Do whatever you want here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set onEditorActionListener for the EditText to implement the action you want to perform.

```
theIP.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            try {
            myIP = theIP.getText().toString(); 
            validIP = ipvalidator.validate(myIP);
        } catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log.d("Error", "Input address is NULL.");
        }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```